# Save a string into non-initialiazed Variant variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a VBA Macro from another worksheet. I can only pass a string as input (or I want to stick to this structure as any change will results in changing alot of code). However, the available macro is using a Variant:

```vb
Private Sub create_tempsheet(DCMfile As String)
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dcm_files As Variant
    'oeffnen des DCMs
    If DCMfile = "" Then
        dcm_files = Application.GetOpenFilename("dcm-Files(.dcm),*dcm", Title:="Select dcm files", MultiSelect:=True)
    Else
        dcm_files(1) = DCMfile
    End If
    'Rest_OF_CODE
```

the initial variable is `dcm_files` and I introduced the variable `DCMfile`
The above code results in a type missmatch error at line `dcm_files(1) = DCMfile` . The conversion function `CVar` didn't help neither.

Any idea how can I save `DCMfile` into `dcm_files(1)` without changing the two variables types?

Comment: You should use the line `Redim dcm_files(1 To 1)` right below `Else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### GetOpenFilename

- [`GetOpenFilename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename), [`ReDim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement)
- When you do `Dim dcm_files As Variant`, `dcm_files` is not an array, it's a variable of type variant that can hold any variable type including an array.
- When you use `GetOpenFilename` with `MultiSelect` set to `True`, the result will be `False` (a boolean) if you press `Cancel`, or a 1D one-based array if you press `OK` (pick one or more files) which will be passed to the variant.
- You forgot to `ReDim` the variant in the `Else` statement:

  ```
  ReDim dcm_Files(1 to 1)
  ```

  Only now it's (a variant holding) a 1D one-based one-element array.

```vb
Private Sub create_tempsheet(DCMfile As String)
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dcm_files As Variant
    'oeffnen des DCMs
    If DCMfile = "" Then
        dcm_files = Application.GetOpenFilename("dcm-Files(.dcm),*dcm", _
            Title:="Select dcm files", MultiSelect:=True)
        If dcm_files = False Then
            MsgBox "You canceled."
            Exit Sub ' or whatever
        End If
    Else
        ReDim dcm_files(1 To 1)
        dcm_files(1) = DCMfile
    End If
     
    ' Print the file names in the VBE Immediate window (Ctrl+G)
    'Debug.Print Join(dcm_files, vbLf)
     
    'Rest_OF_CODE

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's giving you error because `dcm_files` is not an array, you just need to change `dcm_files(1) = DCMfile` to `dcm_files = DCMfile`.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim dcm_files As Variant
'oeffnen des DCMs
If DCMfile = "" Then
    dcm_files = Application.GetOpenFilename("dcm-Files(.dcm),*dcm", Title:="Select dcm files", MultiSelect:=True)
Else
    dcm_files = DCMfile
End If
```

Comment: it has to be an erray, because multi selection is actually enabled in case `Application.GetOpenFilename` is used. that's why, the code which follows, alwazs accesses `dcm_files(1)` first

Comment: Please refer to VBasic2008's answer!